# How can I customize the appearance of Windows Phone?

Tags: settings

To what extent can I change and customize the appearance of the Windows Phone interface? Are there built-in customization options or perhaps third-party apps that allow this?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Think about it this way: would this question on the front page on "opening day" attract the audience we want? Beyond that, would this get attention from, say, UI devs or customer support at MS?

Comment: Right. Not the best question for the class of people you've listed. But still, it seems to have a place here and can be answered objectively. :)

Comment: @Aarthi I can't be sure, but I think so. The audience of this site are users of WP, and this seems like something many users will want to know how to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your accent color and background color (black or white) and lock screen image, as well as change your ringtone and other tones.

Beyond that, though, the UI paradigm of Windows Phone (use of live tiles on the home screen) is actually where we're expected to really personalize the phone. It's different than themes or desktop images, like on other phones or on computers, because the Windows Phone UI is intended to be very sparse and content-driven, without lots of UI chrome and fluff.

The start screen consists of any number of tiles, some of which (and increasingly, most of them) are live tiles. Each application that has a live tile often allows customization of its behavior and look&feel, as well. So, your personalization of your phone isn't surrounding the paradigm of color schemes and background images as much as it is centered around the content you want to look at on your phone.

You can get to your applications without dealing with the start screen, but you can choose what goes on there, and what live tiles you want to see. You can place and arrange the tiles on your start screen any way you want, and this layout can have a significant impact on your phone's look and feel and is a significant way of personalizing it.

However, of course the stock options available in Windows Phone aren't always enough. If you want to get particularly artistic and customize further, there are apps that let you specify completely custom tiles for your homescreen that can act as links to apps, websites, or perform other actions. One that I particularly like is called [MegaTile](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/99257287-1047-451d-a519-c2eabe45385d?wa=wsignin1.0). It can take an image and break it up into multiple start screen tiles. The screenshots are a good demonstration of what it can do.

So, that's what's available right now. Microsoft may add more in the future. It's definitely not quite what you may be used to on iOS or even Android, but it's not necessarily as limited as it may seem at first glance. I think people take the fact that live tiles are much more than simple static icons and your ability to organize your start screen for granted and forget that it can have a major impact on the look & feel of your phone.

P.S. Also what may be interesting to note about the lock screen image that not many people may be aware of is that it supports transparency. This is only available when you're not using a PIN code to lock the phone. All you need to do is download and choose a lock screen image with transparent sections and it will just work. I haven't done this for a good while but I have tried it myself and it did work.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone is quite limited in customization, which is mainly the accent color, lock BG and the ability to create yourself some custom tiles using applications. Note though that applications are quite locked out on customization (other than showing tiles), so there's not much third party out there.

However, this might still be coming.

> Microsoft is going to have a meeting with Windows Phone OEMs and carrier partners soon, and "Customization and Differentiation options" is going to be one of the topics on the docket.
>
> — [Microsoft to hold a meeting about Windows Phone customization](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Microsoft-to-hold-meeting-about-Windows-Phone-customization_id29247)

This is mainly aimed at OEMs though, but could possible translate further to customers.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the appearance of your interface by choosing a accent color in the settings menu

Settings -> Theme -> Accent color

You can choose between one of the following colors Magenta, Purple, Teal, Lime, Brown, Pink, Mango, Blue, Red or Green or a special OEM color like Nokia Blue or HTC Green.

In the same settings screen you can also select a background where you can choose between Dark or Light.

That is everything you can customize (You can ofustomize your lock screen by selecting an image and you can select a number of live tiles to be shown on your home screen)

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak or an unlock, here are the options I've seen you can use to customize Windows Phone.

1. Lock screen wallpaper.
2. Theme Background and Accent Color.
3. Location of tiles on Homescreen.
4. Use of apps like [customer tile maker](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/8ccbffa9-bb45-4ec3-ac68-f29d9c2d53d4), [wiztiles](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/54397d90-7f29-46b3-81b9-f78c3fd3b779) or [new group*](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/93ad2492-42b1-4a9d-9999-d67ea86f2abe) to place pictures or text on home screen tiles. (I use these and your homescreen does start looking unique to an extent)

Once you have jailbroken your device you have a few more options like:-

1. Dynamic Backgrounds
2. Custom Home Screen Live Tiles
3. Lock screen widgets.

Sourced from [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-add-widgets-and-dynamic-backgrounds-to-your-windows-phone-lock-screen-homebrew/) and [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-customize-windows-phone-home-screen-live-tiles-with-themes-for-wp7-video-tutorial/):

Comment: Besides all this you also have a very good looking *paid app for this http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/a9e0ebe7-567a-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what other said, you can change the lock screen by changing image.

> 1. On Start, flick left to go to the App list, and then tap Settings  > Lock + wallpaper.
> 2. Tap Change wallpaper.
> 3. Navigate to the picture that you want to use as your wallpaper. If the picture doesn't fit in the frame, pan the picture until you have it where you like it, and then tap Done.
>
> **Tip**
>
> If you turn your phone off and then back on, you can see the new wallpaper right away.
>
> — http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/basics/lock-screens-faq.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Two more options:

1. [Shining Themes](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=8c333b82-d53a-4633-b6ce-3220aa8d5aac) app
2. [Lockscreen Style](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=14cb65f4-91cc-42ef-9c03-84a8acc24df5) app

These can help you customize your phone to a good extent.