# What do I need to do to get a custom ringtone?

Tags: zune, ringtone

People like [customizing the appearance](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-can-i-customize-the-appearance-of-windows-phone) of their WP7; however, I've been wondering if it is possible to use your own ringtone instead of one of the provided ringtones.

Two questions regarding this:

1. What ringtone formats are supported?
2. In which way do I need to get my ringtone on the phone? Can I do this with Zune?

Comment: +1 How would you change the SMS tone on a windows 7.5 phone?...I read that changing the SMS tone isn't as trivial as changing the ringtone is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What formats are supported?

- It can be either Windows Media Audio (WMA) or MP3 format
- It must be DRM free
- It must be less than 40 seconds long
- It must be smaller than 1 megabyte

> In which way do I need to get my ringtone on the phone? Can I do this with Zune?

1. Yes, you use Zune to do this. If you save the ringone in a folder Zune is already watching the skip to the next step; otherwise just drag/drop the ringtone into the Zune window first.
2. Once the ringtone is in Zune, you need to set the Genre to "ringtone". You do this by simply doing a `right click` > `edit settings`, and then save your changes.
3. Sync your phone to move the new ringtone over.
4. Go to your phone settings and select the new ringtone. If it isn't working, make sure the ringtone you created meets the criteria laid out above, and that the genre is "ringtone"

Comment: Thanks, sounds more easy than I thought. Didn't know about the Genre, the restrictions are handy too.

Answer (score 1):

To create a ringtone using the Zune software
Open the Zune software and find the file you want to turn into a ringtone.

Right-click the file, then click Edit.

In the GENRE list, click or type ringtone, then click OK.

Connect your phone to your computer using a cable, then sync the file to your phone.

On Start, flick left to the App list, then tap Settings  > Ringtones + sounds.

Tap the Ringtone list, then find the new ringtone you've just added.