# Personalise ringtone for SMS or mail

Tags: sms, personalization, ringtone

I looked to [that post](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/481/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-a-custom-ringtone) to personalise ringtones. But ringtones are not available as 'Alerts'.

Do you think there's any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not provide personalize alert sounds without rooting your phone. I don't have it on me (I will try to find it tonight when I am home), but I *believe* I have seen an app on the XDA forums that allows you to **replace existing alerts** with new ones.

Again, your phone has to be developer unlocked and have the root tools supplied. If anyone knows of the app I am referring to, please edit this to provide the name.

Comment: Does **rooting** has the same meaning than **jailbreaking**? Do you have a link which explains how to do it as easily and safely as possible?

Comment: @VaïkGodard The windows phone is a two step process. 1st you have to be developer unlocked. the easiest way is to pay the 99$/yr subscription to the app hub. Once that is done you can search for the "rooting" tools for your specific phone. The process is too long for a comment. If you want, post a question on how to root your phone. Make sure you specify what phone you have

Comment: I'll not do it for the moment but gimme the name of the appli when you have it. I might later become WP developper... "Never say never!"